# Finding numbers NOT in a RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a file contains many numbers ranging from 1 to 10000 without sorting, and each number is spliced by " ". A specific number may also appear many times.
 Like:

2 3 4 2 10 45 3 ....

I hope to get a sorted list which is made up of numbers that does not appear in this file. To illustrate clearly, let the range be 1(inclusive) to 10(inclusive) (not 1 to 10000)

and the file is:

2 3 6 3 5 7 8 4 7

I hope to get the list as following:

1 9 10.

If in Java, I just need to use a TreeSet, and delete the number appear in the file, and the remaining is what I want. But How could I do it in Spark? I just begin to learn Spark and scala, And have the following question?

1.Is there a data structure like treeSet in spark or scala? if not, what should I do.

2.Spark will divide the file into several part and execute concurrently. If it is, How could I make the treeSet shared by different part? Is it a good idea to achieve use my goal?
Thanks.

Comment: But 4 is in your list, shouldn't it be 1 9 10 ? I don't get it...

Comment: yes, I CHANGE my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `subtract`:

```
val fileRDD = sc.makeRDD(List(2,3,4))
val fullRDD = sc.makeRDD(1 to 5)
fullRDD.subtract(fileRDD).collect //1,5
```

Comment: ok, I will try this method. If the number in the file is already sorted, like 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 7 8, is there any better methods? Thanks.

Comment: Without looking at the impl, I would guess not and that it is already fairly efficient....but that is an off the cuff response